# How does one read the PPC op-code 'extrwi'

Tags: assembly, powerpc

I understand it is a mnemoic to rlwinm with its values tweaked, but I was wondering what the actual letter represent when read.  For instance, rlwinm means Rotate Left Word Immediate then aNd with Mask.  If I know what it stands for, I can memorize it a bit easier.

Comment: Extract and right justify immediate, I literally found that in ten seconds with google. I'm not entirely sure where the `w` comes from - `word`? source: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.aixassem/doc/alangref/fixed_rotate_shift32.htm

Comment: Yep, w is for word (32-bit) and d is for doubleword (64-bit).

Comment: My 2 minutes of google failed me then.  Make it a standard answer if you wish and I'll reward you for your google-fu abilities :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Extract and right justify immediate](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.aixassem/doc/alangref/fixed_rotate_shift32.htm).